# (virtual env)(global env) why is this happening instead of just (virtual env) when I activate it?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Also from my understanding if I download a package in a virtual environment if I come back to it, will still be there however my django package is gone. why is that?

Comment: Well, *did* you forget to activate the virtualenv?

Comment: Nope I did activate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to install it again as a virtualEnv isolate your previous installation

Comment: I understand that it is isolated system but if I installed django in that specific environment shouldn't I be able to access it? I thought virtual environment separates from other but keeps what it installed within that env.

Comment: No because you might want to work with different version of Django or packages.
So you have to install django again with a PIP install

Comment: I did do it, in (virtual_env)(base) however when I run pip freeze on (base) django shows up. I thought it is supposed to only stay in (virtual_evn)(base). No?

Comment: Virtualenv is like installing python fresh, you must then from within the virtualenv install the packages you wish to be available. You can write a requirements file with a bit of googling which will save some time

Comment: I understand but isn't it supposed to keep what i've downloaded? It doesn't seem convenient to install all the things i've already installed everytime I comeback to it...

Comment: No. It is the expected outcome. If you didn't use a virtual env which isn't recommended, then it would still be available.

Comment: All virtualenv are separate from one another and the main python installation packages and modules within it's recognised namespace

Comment: Have a look at the files actually within a virtualenv folder. You will understand better I think

Comment: I'm coming back to it to run server

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment since I don't have enough reputation but here are a few things you can do to debug this problem.

1. Check that you activated the correct virtualenv (or pipenv).
2. Once activated, run `pip freeze` in the terminal and check if django comes up as one of the packages installed.
3. If django doesn't show up there, you will need to install it again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. but why do I need to download it again? I've downloaded in the same environment before.

Comment: @HaneulKim Is the environment running? Did the output that you got from `pip freeze` have django listed in it?
Also, if it is listed, just try to run python in the terminal where the virtualenv is running. Then do an `import django` to see what it returns.

Comment: yes it is running. It was not listed so I downloaded again however it got downloaded in base environment as well.

Comment: Yeah, like you gathered from the other answer, virtualenv makes an isolated environment. I'm not sure what you mean by "base environment". I assume you mean the global python that you have installed? I would suggest to not install django globally but only in the virtualenv that you spin up for your project.

Comment: Yeah global environment. I did only install django in virtual environment but it got installed in both.

Comment: From your problem, it sounds like it wasn't installed in the virtualenv. That's why it didn't show up in `pip freeze`. It can happen when you forget to activate the environment before installing django.
If the environment was active, one command shouldn't install in both places.

Comment: it does show up... in both global and virtual environment.